# Getting swipe events while editing table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my `UITableview`, all my cells are editable, `.Delete` being their editing style. For my logic -- whose explanation is irrelevant to the scope of this discussion -- to work, I have to get the events when the user swipes left or if the user decides not to delete the cell at all and swipes right. (It is enough if I get events when the user starts swiping. I don't need the continuos swipe events.) Is this possible? Are there any delegate methods I can use that give me such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d like to refer to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:)

You can use the delegate method:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

This method will be called when a user swipes horizontally in the cell or as apple would like to state it:

> This method is called when the user swipes horizontally across a row; as a consequence, the table view sets its editing property to true (thereby entering editing mode) and displays a Delete button in the row identified by indexPath. In this "swipe to delete" mode the table view does not display any insertion, deletion, and reordering controls. This method gives the delegate an opportunity to adjust the application's user interface to editing mode. When the table exits editing mode (for example, the user taps the Delete button), the table view calls tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Oh, man! How did I miss this? I have googled, trust me! My autocomplete is messed up, I can't browse through them as well. Thanks.